# Same macro on two different worksheets - works on one, aborts on the other

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I have tested on a development workbook. This macro runs successfully and provides the expected results. When I copy this macro to the production version of the workbook, the macro aborts for different reasons. When I step through the macro on debug, the code does nor execute as expected. For example, in the production version, the IF statement testing the date executes, followed by the first .Cells statement then the macro aborts.

No clue on why. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Cost_Per_day
Dim COST_kg
Dim AVG_SALES_PRICE
Dim COST_NET_PURCHASE
Dim PROFIT_GROSS
Dim PROFIT_NET
Dim PROFIT_NET_X
Dim Flag_set

Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim Rw As Long

'If Critical Cells change, move contents to Log sheet

Dim Xrg As Range
Set Xrg = Range("E5:I11")
If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("E5:I11 ")) Is Nothing Then



dtmTime = Now()
Cost_day = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("E7").Value
COST_kg = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("F7").Value
AVG_SALES_PRICE = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I5").Value
COST_NET_PURCHASE = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("G11").Value
PROFIT_GROSS = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I7").Value
PROFIT_NET = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I8").Value
PROFIT_NET_X = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I9").Value



Rw = Sheets("LOG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With Sheets("LOG")
    datcomp = .Cells(Rw - 1, 1)

   ' if the previous entry date is the same as the current date, do not create the entries... one entry per day`

    If Year(datcomp) = Year(dtmTime) And Month(datcomp) = Month(dtmTime) And Day(datcomp) = Day(dtmTime) Then GoTo NoUpd

    .Cells(Rw, 1) = dtmTime
    .Cells(Rw, 2) = Cost_Per_day
    .Cells(Rw, 3) = COST_kg
    .Cells(Rw, 4) = AVG_SALES_PRICE
    .Cells(Rw, 5) = COST_NET_PURCHASE
    .Cells(Rw, 6) = PROFIT_GROSS
    .Cells(Rw, 7) = PROFIT_NET
    .Cells(Rw, 8) = PROFIT_NET_X
    .Cells(Rw, 11) = .Cells(Rw - 1, 1)
 NoUpd:
 End With

 End If

 End Sub`
```

Comment: Please share your data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it will fire always on the calculation event of the worksheet. `If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("E5:I11 ")) Is Nothing Then` will be always true. From the code it may be assumed .that it is intended to fire from  `Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS")` and the data will be feed into the range E5:I11. If this assumption is true it is better to use Change event of  `Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS")`

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:  Data is being feed into sheet FEED_ANALYSIS range E5:I11. [image: Assumed layout]
Following Problem guessed:

1. After first change in any cell (or calculate event) of FEED_ANALYSIS, current date is being added to col A in sheet LOG with variable `dtmTime` (and being treated as `datcomp` in next event). So further update of LOG from cell changes in FEED_ANALYSIS are prevented as if clause is comparing `dtmTime` with `datcomp`  and branching to `NoUpd:`.
2. I think the code will be fired always on the calculation event of the worksheet. `If Not Intersect(Xrg, Range("E5:I11 ")) Is Nothing Then` will be always true.
3. Typo of `Cost_Per_day` and `Cost _day` may be throwing error at `.Cells(Rw, 2) = Cost_Per_day`

if the above assumptions are correct, may try the code in FEED_ANALYSIS. Tried to keep modifications minimal.

```
Option Explicit       'added
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Cost_Per_day
Dim COST_kg
Dim AVG_SALES_PRICE
Dim COST_NET_PURCHASE
Dim PROFIT_GROSS
Dim PROFIT_NET
Dim PROFIT_NET_X
Dim Flag_set
Dim dtmTime As Date
Dim datcomp As Date   'added
Dim Rw As Long
Dim LastRw As Long    ' added
Dim PrvRw As Long     'added
'If Critical Cells change, move contents to Log sheet

Dim Xrg As Range
Set Xrg = Range("E5:I11")
If Not Intersect(Target, Xrg) Is Nothing Then

dtmTime = Now()
Cost_Per_day = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("E7").Value  ' Cost_day changed to Cost_Per_day as per Dim
COST_kg = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("F7").Value
AVG_SALES_PRICE = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I5").Value
COST_NET_PURCHASE = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("G11").Value
PROFIT_GROSS = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I7").Value
PROFIT_NET = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I8").Value
PROFIT_NET_X = Worksheets("FEED_ANALYSIS").Range("I9").Value


LastRw = Sheets("LOG").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
PrvRw = LastRw - 1
With Sheets("LOG")
    datcomp = .Cells(PrvRw, 1)

   ' if the previous entry date is the same as the current date then
   ' choose previous entry row to update other data
   ' else
   ' Chose last row  for new entry
   ' But this approach will not work if data is not enetered  for some unforeseen
   ' reason before 23:59 hrs of currect date i.e dtmTime = Now()
   ' Better to use datetime from a manually entered cell in sheet "FEED_ANALYSIS"
   ' with some validation

    If Year(datcomp) <> Year(dtmTime) Or Month(datcomp) <> Month(dtmTime) Or Day(datcomp) <> Day(dtmTime) Then
    Rw = LastRw
    .Cells(Rw, 1) = dtmTime
    Else
    Rw = PrvRw
    End If

    .Cells(Rw, 1) = dtmTime
    .Cells(Rw, 2) = Cost_Per_day
    .Cells(Rw, 3) = COST_kg
    .Cells(Rw, 4) = AVG_SALES_PRICE
    .Cells(Rw, 5) = COST_NET_PURCHASE
    .Cells(Rw, 6) = PROFIT_GROSS
    .Cells(Rw, 7) = PROFIT_NET
    .Cells(Rw, 8) = PROFIT_NET_X
    .Cells(Rw, 11) = .Cells(Rw - 1, 1)
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Answer would read better with proper indenting. Kudos for getting rid of the `GOTO`!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am sure by viewing my code you have determined that I am completely new to this.  I still have 2 issues.  1) FEED_ANALYSIS is a sheet that has no manual input fields therefore the code will not execute.  2) ive added the code to the FEED_ANALYSIS sheet (right click on name, view code, copy paste code), and now code does not execute at all in either debug (F8, or F5), or if i actualy manualy change fields in the change array.  Any suggestions?

Comment: May try the simplest approach to shift the code to the sheet where manual feeding in taking place. Then modify line `Set Xrg = Range("E5:I11")` with range that is causing changes in the 7 variables in sheet FEED_ANALYSIS. Could not understand 2nd point in your comment., Did you actually manually changed any cells in the range E5:I11 in sheet FEED_ANALYSIS and still failed to trigger the code? It is working in my trial.Please share How the data is being handled  and how you want to trigger the code for exploring other alternatives.

Comment: Execution of the code can be tested by changes in sheet LOG only. After manual change in FEED_ANALYSIS, go to LOG and check for changed value. Alternatively may use `Msgbox` or `Debug.Print` in various stages of the procedure and manually change critical cells in FEED_ANALYSIS to test.execution of the code..